# How to get Superscript over subscript in XML?

Tags: android, xml, subscript, superscript

I'm coding a program for Android, and I have to display some text with chemistry notation. 
Using regular subscripting works when it is defined as a String resource, like this:

```
<string name="OH">OH<sup>-</sup>, [mg/l]</string>
```

This will show up as "OH<sup>-</sup>, [mg/l]".

However, I need the sign for Carbonate where I've tried this:

```
<string name="CO23">CO<sup>2-</sup><sub>3</sub>, [mg/l]</string>
```

Which looks like this: CO<sup>2-</sup><sub>3</sub>

I need the 3 to be under the 2-..

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out yet? I'm working with the same concept at the moment.

Comment: No, nothing yet.. I also have a problem where subscript and superscript doesn't work in spinners or listviews..

Comment: That's curious. I have it working in a listview. Thats actually what I am putting mine in right now. I just haven't found how to stack the sup and sub.

Comment: Do you define the string in the java code using setText, or as a defined string in Strings.xml?

Comment: I'm doing it in the Strings.xml file. I know what you might be missing though. I had to add a bit in order to get part of it to work. I have my strings formatted like so: <item><![CDATA[<html>Al<sup><small>3+</small></sup></html>]]></item>, and then in my code I have the .setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

Comment: How do you access the different textviews in the listview so you can change the text? Do you use a custom adapter?

Comment: Yes, I am using a custom adapter.

Comment: Did you figure this out or find some solution?

Comment: I managed to get superscript to work in spinners and listview, as all you had to do was replace "<sub>...</sub>" in a string array with "&lt;sub>...&lt;/sub>". That was it works.
No solution to the original problem though..